# MSAL4J - token generation error : Unknown or Invalid instance

Tags: java, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to generate token using MSAL4j-1.8 jar in my Java application.
Below is the code I am using :

```
private static IAuthenticationResult getAccessTokenByClientCredentialGrant() throws Exception {

        ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(
                clientId,
                ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(secret))
                .authority(authority)
                .build();

        // With client credentials flows the scope is ALWAYS of the shape "resource/.default", as the
        // application permissions need to be set statically (in the portal), and then granted by a tenant administrator
        ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(
                Collections.singleton(scope))
                .build();

        CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);
        return future.get();
    }
```

I get an error :

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS50049: Unknown or invalid instance.
Trace ID: c6a936bf-2b0f-489e-ada3-d2311e708500
Correlation ID: f515dd78-7915-43d7-9020-62631f27c955
Timestamp: 2020-12-10 16:14:09Z
      at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.validate(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:147)
      at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.doInstanceDiscoveryAndCache(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:138)
      at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.getMetadataEntry(AadInstanceDiscoveryProvider.java:42)
      at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.getAuthorityWithPrefNetworkHost(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:32)
      at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:59)
      at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:59)
      at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:17)
      at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1601)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Any idea on what can be the problem?

Comment: What did you set as the authority?

Comment: How's going? has your issue got solved?

Answer (score 3):

As @juunas asked, seems there is something wrong with your `authority` setting.
Try the code below:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientCredentialFactory;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientCredentialParameters;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ConfidentialClientApplication;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.IAuthenticationResult;

public class AADClientCred {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String tenantID = "<your tenant ID or name>";
        String clientID = "<your Azure AD app id>";
        String Secret = "<your azure ad app secret>";
        String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID;
        //I use microsoft graph as resource for demo
        String scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";

        try {
            String access_token = getAccessTokenByClientCredentialGrant(clientID, Secret, authority, scope)
                    .accessToken();

            System.out.println("access token : " + access_token);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static IAuthenticationResult getAccessTokenByClientCredentialGrant(String clientID, String Secret,
            String authority, String scope) throws Exception {

        ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication
                .builder(clientID, ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(Secret)).authority(authority).build();

        ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters
                .builder(Collections.singleton(scope)).build();

        CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);
        return future.get();
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue with `Microsoft.Identity.Web` while trying to get a client credentials token.

```cs
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(configuration, Constants.AzureAdB2C)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new[] {configuration["TodoApi:Scope"] }!)
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

This was my original config,

```json
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://mydomain.b2clogin.com/
    "TenantId": "502be9ac-db65-41f1-b368-807e9868043e",
    "ClientId": "7909238a-5a24-4da4-9960-e701d0dd3ed3",
    "ClientCredentials": [
      {
        "SourceType": "ClientSecret",
        "ClientSecret": "<secret-value>"
      }
    ]
  },
  "TodoApi":{
      "Scope": "https://mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/todo-api-client-id-or-name/.default"
    }
```

Then I changed the instance to what was suggested as authority in the other answer,

```
    "Instance": "https://mydomain.b2clogin.com/tfp/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/<b2c_policy_name>",
```

This works. However the documentation for this library never clarifies that nor  does the error. Had it mentioned the word Authority, it was easier to fix. Surprisingly same issue exists on the service side, but there the workaround is different